# NoSQL server solution for a mobile chat app?

Tags: ios, database, mobile, nosql, chat

I'm writing a chat program for iOS (and eventually Android). I'd like to write the server code in Rails, since it's what I'm most comfortable with. I'm loosely basing my initial design on [this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ioschat/index.html) to start with, though the application will eventually be far more complex.

I'm wondering whether it would make sense at all for the app's performance to go with a nosql solution for storing chat messages, rather than MySQL or postgreSQL. And, if yes, what nosql solution might be best -- mongodb, couchdb, Cassandra, etc.?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo's a good choice you can setup it fast and use it rightaway there's also a good api for it http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.5.2/ and of course http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started

Cheers :)